# Using .Autofilter , using results in Textbox.value

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Im using .autofilter to filter a list in excel, my problem is i want to have the results from the autofilter populate textboxes. i know i can use something similar to

```
textbox.text = Data(a1).value
```

however as the cells are filtered they keep there original cell location so i cant just use the cell location. There will only ever be one result to the filter so i need something that populates the text boxes from the row just under the filter heading.

for back ground the over all idea is to have a spread sheet that can be searched from a userform, which currently works, and then display the results in text boxes. Keeping the user of the spreadsheet away from the raw data as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` can help you... Your code could look like this:

```
Sheet1.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1,1).Value
```

I haven't tried it...

Answer (score 0):

If you only will ever have 1 result, the following works:

`textbox.text = Sheet1.Range("myrange").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value`

but you will get a type mismatch if there is more than 1 result in the filter.